# SELECT with JOIN limited

Tags: mysql, join, sql

I have the follow query:

```
SELECT pro.* 
  FROM tb_AutProposta pro, tb_AutParcelamento par 
 WHERE pro.id = par.id
```

But, want to limit each `tb_AutParcelamento` to 1. Tried "Subselect", but without success.

The table pro is an contract and par is the parcels of this contract. For each contract, is generated n parcels, and, for each parcel is generated a due date, and I need to know the last due date for each contract.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the table par, and what exactly do you want this query to return?  The first par.Id?

Comment: This almost exact same question is asked almost every day! Did you try searching before posting your question?

Comment: @Mangist The table pro is an contract and par is the parcels of this contract. I want to return only the due parcel from each contract. But, my question is only how to limit the query, because all other things I can do =P

Comment: @MarkByers Yeap, I tried the searched questions, but without success.

Comment: How do you know which is the "due" parcel? What about a parcel makes it "due"?

Comment: @MarkByers For each contract, is generated n parcels, and, for each parcel is generated a due date, and I need to know the last due date for each contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made up some field names because we don't know your exact table structure.

This query works under the assumptions:

- you want the latest ("highest") parcel due date for each related contract
- you have fields for `due_date` and `pro_id` in your parcel table. (`tb_AutParcelamento.pro_id` being a foreign key to the `tb_AutProposta.id`)
- i made up `pro_id` because i assume the condition `pro.id = par.id` is wrong, when the `id` fields in both tables are auto increment values and the primary key in each table.

```
SELECT pro.*, MAX(par.due_date) as latest_due_date
FROM tb_AutProposta pro
LEFT JOIN tb_AutParcelamento par
    ON pro.id = par.pro_id
GROUP BY pro.id
```

Comment: This is simpler than my solution, however it is not as flexible. If more columns need to be selected from the `tb_AutParcelamento` table, the data in those other columns will not be aligned with the maximum date. If all that is needed is the max date and nothing else, then this solution should be chosen.

Comment: @ZaneBien thats right, then it is a groupwise maximum and requires a more sophisticated query like yours

Answer (score 1):

Without really knowing your data schema, and what you're trying to do, you could try to limit the number of par records returned.

```
SELECT pro.*, FIRST(par.Id) as FirstParcel
FROM tb_AutProposta pro, tb_AutParcelamento par 
WHERE pro.id = par.id
GROUP BY pro.*
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a question involving the retrieval of the group-wise maximum/minimum of a set of records. The method I like to use is as follows:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.due_date
FROM
    tb_AutProposta a
INNER JOIN
    tb_AutParcelamento b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(due_date) AS last_due_date
        FROM tb_AutParcelamento
        GROUP BY id
    ) c ON b.id = c.id AND b.due_date = c.last_due_date
```

Replace `due_date` with the actual name of the date field in `tb_AutParcelamento`.

Comment: actually what the OP requests is not a groupwise max and can be selected much easier, as you can read in the other answers.